# event.prevendefault() not working inside a function that has an each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have function that will do a simple validation, if every input text is empyt an alert will pop up, and the program will stop. Function will fire up after a click of a button. I'm allready passing the event, but somehow the event.PreventDefault() not working, so still accessing the server side code.
Below is the function to do simple validation.

```
var checkRequired = function(event)         
  $('.box-load .requir').each(function(index,item) {
    var index = $(item).data('index');
    if(index === 'text') {
      if ($(item).val() == "") {
        $(this).focus();
        alert('Please input the required parameter');
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

For the trigger the function I use this code:

```
$(document).on('click','.box-load .btn-save', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
checkRequired(event);
```

Bellow the checkRequired(), I'm gonna do an ajax request. What i want is, if one of the input text is empty, the event is stop. But with that code, is not working. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modify your `checkRequired()` to return a boolean, and then in your click handler test that return value and only do the Ajax if it worked. Having `event.preventDefault()` inside `checkRequired()` doesn't make sense, because you've already called `event.preventDefault()` in your click handler, and also `.preventDefault()` has nothing to do with stopping your Ajax code, it only prevents the default (non-JS) behaviour of the clicked button.

Comment: looks like your buttons are kind of submit buttons. So the first `event.preventDefault` should work, there must be something strange in how you know if the server side code is run due to the form submission?

Answer (score 0):

if you call `event.preventDefault()`, default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$(document).on('click','.box-load .btn-save', function(event) 
{    
     checkRequired(event);
     event.preventDefault();
```

`event.preventDefault()` should be outside the for loop.

```
var checkRequired = function(event)    
{      
      $('.box-load .requir').each(function(index,item) {
        var index = $(item).data('index');
        if(index === 'text') {
          if ($(item).val() == "") {
            $(this).focus();
            alert('Please input the required parameter');
          }
        }
      });
 event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for the suggestion, now is working like what u been told. Thanks a lot,

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it helps you. you can accept as the answer if it help you.

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() will just stop the default action, not stop your function call. If you don't specifically `return` from your function, it will go on and launch the ajax.